# Multiple summary data in crosstab row (duplicate)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crosstab

My time table report takes in this data:

```
Time    Day        Section
 10AM   Sunday       10
 10AM   Sunday       20
 9PM    Monday       5
 11PM   Tuesday      4
```

I want the following output in my crosstab.

[image]

But I only get one value in each section per a given Time and Same Day. I need to show multiple values across each row. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the report. This isn't useful and it's hard to see where the issue may lay without an actual screenshot.

Comment: issue is simple one row value i want to display two records.Example 10 AM i want to display section 10 and 20 but only 10 is showing